# I can't find file `art11.sty'. <to be read again> \relax \input art1\@ptsize.sty\relax

Tags: latex-2.09

package code:

```
\documentstyle[11pt]{articlesec}
%\documentclass[11pt]{articlesec}
%\usepackage{latexsym,articlesec} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\textwidth 15.5cm
\textheight 24.7cm
\topmargin -2.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.71cm
\evensidemargin 0.71cm
```

articlesec.sty file:

```
% article.sty 23 Sep 85
\typeout{Document Style 'article'. Released 23 September 1985}

\def\@ptsize{0} 
\@namedef{ds@11pt}{\def\@ptsize{1}}
\@namedef{ds@12pt}{\def\@ptsize{2}} 
\def\ds@twoside{\@twosidetrue \@mparswitchtrue} \def\ds@draft{\overfullrule
5pt} 
\@options
\input art1\@ptsize.sty\relax

\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.} 
\def\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}} 
\def\labelenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\def\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\def\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\def\labelenumiii{\roman{enumiii}.}
\def\theenumiii{\roman{enumiii}}
\def\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\def\labelenumiv{\Alph{enumiv}.}
\def\theenumiv{\Alph{enumiv}} 
\def\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}

\def\labelitemi{$\bullet$}
\def\labelitemii{\bf --}
\def\labelitemiii{$\ast$}
\def\labelitemiv{$\cdot$}

\def\verse{\let\\=\@centercr 
 \list{}{\itemsep\z@ \itemindent -1.5em\listparindent \itemindent 
 \rightmargin\leftmargin\advance\leftmargin 1.5em}\item[]}
\let\endverse\endlist
\def\quotation{\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em
 \itemindent\listparindent
 \rightmargin\leftmargin \parsep 0pt plus 1pt}\item[]}
\let\endquotation=\endlist
\def\quote{\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[]}
\let\endquote=\endlist

\def\descriptionlabel#1{\hspace\labelsep \bf #1}
\def\description{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
 \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
\let\enddescription\endlist


\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}


\def\titlepage{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \else \newpage \fi \thispagestyle{empty}\c@page\z@}
\def\endtitlepage{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi}

\arraycolsep 5pt \tabcolsep 6pt \arrayrulewidth .4pt \doublerulesep 2pt 
\tabbingsep \labelsep 

\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\fboxsep = 3pt \fboxrule = .4pt 

\newcounter{part}
\newcounter {section}
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]

\def\thepart{\Roman{part}} \def\thesection {\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection {\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection {\thesubsection .\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\theparagraph {\thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\def\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\arabic{subparagraph}}

\def\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\def\@tocrmarg {2.55em}
\def\@dotsep{4.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\def\tableofcontents{\section*{Contents\markboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}}
 \@starttoc{toc}}
\def\l@part#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}
 \addvspace{2.25em plus 1pt} \begingroup
 \@tempdima 3em \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth \parfillskip
-\@pnumwidth 
 {\large \bf \leavevmode #1\hfil \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
 \nobreak \endgroup}
\def\l@section#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty} \addvspace{1.0em plus 1pt}
\@tempdima 1.5em \begingroup
 \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth 
 \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth 
 \bf \leavevmode #1\hfil \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
 \endgroup}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\listoffigures{\section*{List of Figures\markboth
 {LIST OF FIGURES}{LIST OF FIGURES}}\@starttoc{lof}}
\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\listoftables{\section*{List of Tables\markboth
 {LIST OF TABLES}{LIST OF TABLES}}\@starttoc{lot}}
\let\l@table\l@figure


\def\thebibliography#1{\section*{References\markboth
 {REFERENCES}{REFERENCES}}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}
 \sloppy
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist


\newif\if@restonecol
\def\theindex{\@restonecoltrue\if@twocolumn\@restonecolfalse\fi
\columnseprule \z@
\columnsep 35pt\twocolumn[\section*{Index}]
 \markboth{INDEX}{INDEX}\thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
 \parskip\z@ plus .3pt\relax\let\item\@idxitem}
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40pt}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{20pt}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40pt \hspace*{30pt}}
\def\endtheindex{\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\def\indexspace{\par \vskip 10pt plus 5pt minus 3pt\relax}

\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@ 
 \hrule width .4\columnwidth 
 \kern 2.6\p@} 

\newenvironment{foottitle}%
{\begin{list}{\hspace\labelsep {\large *}}%
{\itemsep 0pt\topsep 0pt\partopsep 0pt
\baselineskip 15.0pt\parindent 0pt
\settowidth\labelwidth{\hspace\labelsep {\large *}}%
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}}%
{\end{list}}

\long\def\@makefntext#1{\begin{foottitle}\item #1\end{foottitle}}



\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\def\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\def\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\def\textfraction{.2}
\def\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\def\dbltopfraction{.7}
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
 \vskip 10pt 
 \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1: #2}
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize \unhbox\@tempboxa\par \else \hbox
to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil} 
 \fi}


\newcounter{figure}
\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{Figure \thefigure}
\def\figure{\@float{figure}}
\let\endfigure\end@float
\@namedef{figure*}{\@dblfloat{figure}}
\@namedef{endfigure*}{\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}
\def\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{Table \thetable}
\def\table{\@float{table}}
\let\endtable\end@float
\@namedef{table*}{\@dblfloat{table}}
\@namedef{endtable*}{\end@dblfloat}


\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
 \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
 \def\@makefnmark{\hbox 
 to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}} 
 \if@twocolumn 
 \twocolumn[\@maketitle] 
 \else \newpage
 \global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle \fi\thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax
 \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \vskip 1.2cm \begin{center}
 {\LARGE \@title \par} \vskip 1.5em {\large \lineskip .5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author 
 \end{tabular}\par} 
 \vskip 1em {\large \@date} \end{center}
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em} 
\def\abstract{\if@twocolumn
\section*{Abstract}
\else \small 
\begin{center}
{\bf Abstract\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}} 
\end{center}
\quotation 
\fi}
\def\endabstract{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}

\mark{{}{}} 

\if@twoside \def\ps@headings{\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\rm
\thepage\hfil \sl \leftmark}\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\sl \rightmark \hfil
\rm\thepage}\def\sectionmark##1{\markboth {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth
>\z@
 \thesection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}{}}\def\subsectionmark##1{\markright
{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
 \thesubsection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}}
\else \def\ps@headings{\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}\def\@oddhead{\hbox
{}\sl \rightmark \hfil \rm\thepage}\def\sectionmark##1{\markright
{\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
 \thesection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}}}
\fi
\def\ps@myheadings{\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\sl\rightmark \hfil
\rm\thepage}\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\rm \thepage\hfil\sl\leftmark\hbox
{}}\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}


\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
 January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
 July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
 \space\number\day, \number\year}

\ps@plain \pagenumbering{arabic} \onecolumn \if@twoside\else\raggedbottom\fi
```

Comment: You should try this with `\documentclass[11pt]{article} \usepackge{articlesec}`...

Comment: Are you really still using LaTeX2.09? The `\documentstyle` directive strongly suggests you do. Why?? Why not use `\documentclass` from LaTeX2e? After all, it's only been the standard for the past 23+ years...

Comment: Thanks Werner !!!. It works with \documentclass[11pt]{article}, but it shows the same error (this time with art10.sty not found) again if I use \documentclass[11pt]{article} \usepackge{articlesec}..

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, change `\input art1\@ptsize.sty\relax` to `\input size1\@ptsize.sty\relax`.

Comment: `art10.sty` has not been part of latex since 1993, wherever did you find this file?

Comment: just use `\documentclass{article}` and don't use `articlesec` at all.

Comment: Perhaps the question tag should be changed from `latex3` to `latex2.09` (if such a tag exists).